# Prevent interaction to make use of non-Polygons

Tags: openlayers

How do I customize an interaction (for example ol.interaction.Modify) in order to prevent Point and LineString Geometries to be interacted with?

```
    let interaction =  new ol.interaction.Modify({
        source: this.source
    });
    // do something that prevents non-polygons to 'enter' the interaction
```

Comment: ok if this helps, you're welcome

Comment: The simplest way would be not to use `source` option for modifiable features, but `features` option, where you specify only features that are allowed to be modified.